# How to optimize a list of React Components with props that are functions that require two arguments

Tags: reactjs, optimization, react-hooks

I'm trying to only render the DropdownList items that have changed out of the list of DropdownLists. I've wrapped each DropdownList in a React.memo so I expect it to check each prev and next props. All is okay until working with functions. Each DropdownList has an onChange function where I need to pass the event object along with the map item.

This is because the onChange function will return the value selected but I have no idea of knowing which DropdownList it came from. So I need to pass in the index or item key to the onChange function.

Hopefully I've explained this well enough so that even if my proposed way of solving this isn't right, you'll still understand the problem.

Below is a link to the stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/optimization

Comment: Does this example solve your issue?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/optimization-124kzk

Comment: Yes it does. My updated example now works as well. Thanks!

Comment: Okay.. Don't try to edit the same link you provided in question.. Bcoz when people see the question they will use the link provided in question.. Also add ```key={index}``` to the above ```div``` element  like, ```<div style={{ display: "flex" }} key={index}>``` to get rid of the warning message as well.. Key should be assigned to the immediate element under ```map```..

Comment: Yes, turns out I was only one step away from figuring it out so my example does work. However, I don't think it's the best way to do what I'm saying. For anyone who comes here, I would recommend referencing @ManirajMurugan example above. 

Take a look at the console to see the children don't render when making a selection.